# WCF RESTful services grounding 101

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest, web

Not sure if this is the right place for this question but if not, I'd appreciate it if anyone could suggest a better place to get an answer as I've struggled just with researching on the web as there is too much information and disinformation.

I'm designing a large scale social media website and want to get a very in depth and solid understanding and knowledge of Web API, RESTful web services (C#) and issues around performance, scalability, authentication and data protection etc in the modern web environment.

Can anyone recommend any good books/blogs/resources to start with on this?

My background is 13 years as a developer, largely .NET server side and desktop application/WPF so the web side of things is relatively new to me.

I appreciate any help or pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, in order to understand things, I would suggest to start reading [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942839.aspx) comparing REST and SOAP web services regarding performance, security etc. Since you are a professional, you would not need to buy a book (I guess).

Programmatically, I suppose [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services) would be a good starting point to see an tutorial on creating WCF REST services. [This post](http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api) could guide you on how to build a REST web service using the ASP.NET Web API.

Hope I helped!